# normalize different date formats

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-datetime

I am trying to work with an XML data that has different kinds of (string) date values, like:

'Sun, 04 Apr 2021 13:32:26 +0200'

'Sun, 04 Apr 2021 11:52:29 GMT'

I want to save these in a Django object that has a datetime field.

The script that I have written to convert a str datetime is as below:

```
def normalise(val):
    val = datetime.strptime(val, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
    return val
```

Although, this does not work for every datetime value I scrape. For example for above 2 examples, the script works for the first one but crashes for the second.
What would be an ideal way of normalising all the datetime values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dateutil` module parses many different types of formats.  You can find the doc [here](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

This is a simple example:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from dateutil.parser import parse
    date_strs = ['Sun, 04 Apr 2021 13:32:26 +0200','Sun, 04 Apr 2021 11:52:29 GMT']
    for d in date_strs:
        print(parse(d))
```

output:

```
2021-04-04 13:32:26+02:00
2021-04-04 11:52:29+00:00
```

If there are other date formats that this doesn't cover you can to store specific python format strings keyed by the xml element name.